# Checking records with query

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm doing IT in a school. We work with a program based on a database in Access. The parents fill in the frontname, the name and class of their son or daughter 
and then extra information for us about their child. This must be correct, especially the class.

That's why I put a control (query check class). I have 1 table where I can find all the information of a child (table 'student')
The other table ('information') is what parents fill in. Now I want to see all students whose parents made a mistake:

This is my query, it doesn't work:

```
In (SELECT [class] FROM [information] WHERE (([information].[frontname] = [student].[frontname]) AND ([information].[class] <> [student].[class])))
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is invalid for a few reasons.

1. `IN()` should be taken out. It's an expression used in a comparison, and the placement is incorrect and does nothing to change the resulting data set.
2. You do not call table Information and table Student, but you are comparing the two in your `WHERE` statement.
3. `SELECT [class]` is not explicit. `[class]` exists in both tables, so you need to choose which table's value you want to see. If it's the student table, then it should be `SELECT [student].[class]` Perhaps you want to see both values, so you can see how they differ.
4. Use joins, they are easier to read and understand

So an edit, which may not give you what you want because I don't fully understand your issue, is below:

```
SELECT [student].[class], [information].[class]
FROM [Information]
INNER JOIN [Student]
ON [information].[frontname] = [student].[frontname]
WHERE [information].[class] <> [student].[class];
```

However, you're going to get weird data because you're only comparing front names, so if there are two De Vlieger's at this school, the query is not going to know which one to return.

So a further edit, assuming a "backname" or "lastname" or "surname" field exists in both tables:

```
SELECT [student].[class], [information].[class]
FROM [Information]
INNER JOIN [Student]
ON [information].[frontname] = [student].[frontname]
AND [Information].[surname] = [student].[surname]
WHERE [information].[class] <> [student].[class];
```

Comment: You've made a mistake with the copy and paste, no second `ON` in the join. :)